# Static class var

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a class in node that each object can have a unique id associated with it, so if I have a class Person for example, the first Person object would have ID 1, second would have ID 2 etc.

In Java the solution would be something like this

```
public class Person {

  static int ID = 0;

  public Person() {
    ++ID;
  }
}
```

I've found some solutions but they seem ridiculously long and stupid compared to the implementation in Java, is there a simple way to do this in node like the way I mentioned in Java? Thanks

Comment: What solutions did you find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain js:

```
let ID = 0;

class Person {
  constructor() {
     ++ID;
   }
}
```

May make it a property of Person:

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
     ++Person.ID;
   }

}

Person.ID = 0;
```

---

As you are coming from a Java background, you might just use `typescript` and compile it down to js:

```
class Person {
  public static ID = 0;

  constructor() {
     ++Person.ID;
   }
}
```

(Static properties are currently in the js (ESnext) proposal, so this might become valid js soon...)

---

Some opinion on:

> I've found some solutions but they seem ridiculously long and stupid compared to the implementation in Java

There is *always* a more elegant way to write java code in js.

Comment: I was about to suggest the second approach in another answer. That's the closest to static members in JavaScript, and is how TypeScript deals with it as well.

Comment: @john i mentioned the first as it is obvious for javascriptlers, but its impossible in java.